# How modify the name of a class variable in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to create the class Profile with different names

```
Profile user = new Profile();
```

The field **user** I need every time the program enter there I can choose the value of user or enter by the keyboard.

Profile is a Class in java.

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: Do you expect us to be able to read that?

Comment: You have to put yourself in the shoes of a person who might have the knowledge necessary to answer your question. What information would such a person needs in order to be able to answer your question?

Comment: ok, I am trying to create mutliple objects of a type of class I made. The class is **Profile** but I want to create if is possible with different names every time when the class is called.

Comment: That's not enough. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Create your own class, extend Profile class, write default constructor for this class.
2. Use the class you've created just like Profile class

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save all user names that created while user entering (using `array`, `arraylist`). Then you need search for which username you want on them using `for-loop` or some other way. You can write a `loop` based keyboard entry method for it.